# android webview onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-webview, back

I have webview based app which loads data using both *loadDataWithBaseURL* (remote urls) and *loadUrl* calls (from *assets*).  How do I now handle backPress.

ex use case. 
**step 1** - no default page to show set so show static page from assets.  Lets call this static page as **S1**.  On **S1** we can add pages like bookmarks and set one of them as default like homepage.  Lets call home page as **H1**.

if **H1** set using previous step on **S1** show **H1** using *loadDataWithBaseURL* (I do some preprocessing).

**step 2** - from **H1** I use a href to to go to **S1**.  On **S1** press back  *onBackPressed* is called but its blank page.

So I would like to get your views on how to handle history when we are using *loadDataWithBaseURL*, *loadUrl* (from assets).

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: use nohistory in your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Window.history.back() method or Android finish() method

Comment: sorry did not quite understand.  I on back button click added history.back() like for browser but does nothing.  It would be helpful to know how the history stack is build with load methods of webview.

Comment: Hmm miten if you able to use session tracking means that will be good for you try it out if its not use full means sorry for that...

Comment: you right I ended up handling it in activity which pretty much is like session lifetime.